# Wagtail distinguish page created from page updated

Tags: wagtail

In a wagtail project, I have a `NewsSnippet` snippet which is used for announcements.

Furthermore (slightly simplified), I have a page model `CoursePage` which contains descriptions of the courses that are offered.

Children of `CoursePage` are from the model `Course`. This model just contains `start_date` and `end_date` and a `status` (available or booked out) and some more which I believe is not important for this question.

Adding a new `Course` to a `CoursePage` means that there is a new course of type `CoursePage` at `start_date`. The `Course` model is derived from `AbstractForm` and allows to register for the course at the corresponding date.

I would like to automatically announce (that is, create a `NewsSnippet`) when a new `Course` is created. However, if a `Course` is just updated, I don't want a new `NewsSnippet` to be created. Furthermore, I only want the `NewsSnippet` to be created when the `Course` page is published, not saved as a draft.

I thought this can be either done in the `save` method of a Form used by the `course` model via `base_class_form = Myform`, however, I don't know how to distinguish "publish" from "save as draft" there. I also considered using signals as in the documentation,  and `page_published` looks promising, but the docs say: "This signal is emitted from a `PageRevision` when a revision is set to published." However, I don't want to announce every revision, but just the first creation. Is there a way to find out whether `page_published` is fired for the first time for a `Page`?

Furthermore (this might be a second question), is there good and easy to understand example how to implement signals using the `ready()` method of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider tying into the `after_create_page` hook? That should work:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10/reference/hooks.html#after-create-page

Comment: This hook is also called when a page is saved as a revision. I might fiddle around with a flag in the Page model and `has_unpublished_changes`. Either in the hook you mentioned or in the `page_published` signal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I have implemented it now:

```
# the page model
class MyPage( Page ):
    # model definitions
    pass

# The snippet
class NewsSnippet( models.Model ):
    # Some definitions...
    # A ForeignKey to the PageModel:
    linked_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page', null = True, blank = True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name = '+',
    )

# The function called from the signal:
def publish_news( sender, **kwargs ):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    has_been_published = (
        NewsSnippet.objects.filter( linked_page = instance ) > 0
    )
    if not has_been_published:
        news = NewsSnippet()
        news.linked_page = instance
        # add content according to the snippet definition
        # ...
        news.save()

# register the signal
page_published.connect( publish_news, sender = MyPage )
```

So far, this does what I want. However, the implementation is not (yet) via the `ready()` method of the app. I will see if this has any effects...

Answer (score 0):

For ready() flow
you can create signal.py in your app directory 
and put your receiver logic in it.

Then in your app.py you can use ready() method to initialize those signals.

```
class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'profile'
    verbose_name = "Profiles"

    def ready(self):
        from . profiles import signals
```